# Storing HTML Tags in a Variable with PHP

Tags: php, string

I am trying to store data from an email list into a variable so that I can extract data out of it. I am trying to store everything like this:

I am trying the following:

```
<?php

$data =<<<EOD
Ian Jack <ian.jack@test.co.za>, Andrew Denison <adenison131451504@test.com>, 
EOD;

echo $data . "<br>";

?>
```

I tried to use Heredocs, single quotes or double quote strings but I keep getting this result:

> Ian Jack , Andrew Denison ,

I have looked around and tried output buffers and a few others but nothing seems to stick, I need the text inside the < and > so that I can get the email addresses but the $data variables is not storing it as I assume it is interpreting it as HTML and not recognizing it as a valid HTML tag? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Vortexza

Comment: use regex `(?<=<)[^>]+`

Comment: Use [`htmlspecialchars`](https://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to encode the output, the browser is treating it as HTML.

Comment: You just can't see the content, because they are interpreted as html tags! Use ^ and you will see your content.

Comment: plus, view your HTML source, you'll see it's all in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is outputted, just check the source code of the webpage, in firefox <kbd>ctrl+u</kbd>.

If you want to make the email addresses clickable, you can use:

```
$data =<<<EOD
Ian Jack <a href="mailto:ian.jack@test.co.za">ian.jack@test.co.za</a>, Andrew Denison <a href="mailto:adenison131451504@test.com">adenison131451504@test.com</a>, 
EOD;
echo $data . "<br>";
```

If you just want to display the email addresses, you can simply use:

```
$data =<<<EOD
Ian Jack ian.jack@test.co.za, Andrew Denison adenison131451504@test.com, 
EOD;
echo $data . "<br>";
```

---

Please note that you **should** encode the email addresses if you plan to display them publicly, otherwise you'll get lots of spam...

Please read [php email encode prevent spam](http://davidwalsh.name/php-email-encode-prevent-spam) to understand how to encode emails to be displayed on a webpage.

Comment: Thanks, not actually using it for production. Just learning PHP and ran into this problem. This worked, I will look into heredocs a bit more...

Comment: Heredoc is handy, I use it a lot, I've no patience for quotes and more quotes... GL